# My site is not being responsive, it showing horizontal scroll on viewport set

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

my site is not responsive, even i include the responsive css file in that.

[here is the link of site](http://bit.ly/1ExXXWG)

i tried too hard on that, please help me.
i also include
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` 
and meta `content="320">`in header , please check this link

Comment: You put the wrong link

Comment: no wrong link @MikeRally

Answer (score 2):

Try adjusting the width of your body in your media queries. In your CSS it looks like you set the body to be a min width:

`body {
   min-width: 1024px;
}`

But I didn't catch any width adjustments at the breakpoints in your media queries. If you adjust the body width the elements inside it will respond according to what the parent element is.

Comment: thanks Lindsay, is there any tool online that help to debug responsive queries ??

Answer (score 0):

write in your css file

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1024px){
  //your css settings to compatible with devices 
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply, but i already set this. please check http://bit.ly/1ATEl1R plz guide me if i m wrong

Comment: I tried responsive your website write this code after `@media........ { ul.cms_feature: margin-right:none; .plan_home { width:25%; display:block; margin:auto;  ` that's example for small computer screen you have to make compatible for all devices screen